# What are all of these NAT terms?

Tags: networking, nat, upnp

I (loosely) know about Network Address Translation (NAT) in that the NAT device stores a mapping of external ports to internal ports. However, I started reading about it and got really confused by all of the terms: STUN, ICE, TURN, uPnP, NAT-PMP, full cone NAT, restricted cone NAT, and port restricted cone NAT. Any help sorting out what this all means would be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: There's a huge page on NAT on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). There's no way to give a specific answer to such a general question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thats the problem, i read what's listed there and its too complicated. Isnt there a simple explanation somewhere?

Comment: You can try [How Stuff Works](http://www.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm), but I don't think there's a way to make everything simple.

Comment: @chacham15: If even Wikipedia is too complex, get yourself book(s) on computer networks and start with the basics. You'll have a much stronger foundation to base yourself of when using this knowledge...

Comment: Network Access Translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've covered a lot of different topics with all of those protocols but essentially they are all used to work around or with limitations of NAT when used with public routing. Some deal with port mapping, address mapping, etc.

uPnP is an exception in that it typically allows hosts on the inside of the NAT to talk with the uPnP-enabled device to get statistics like external IP & forwarded ports & generally facilitates easy firewall transversal for applications that require it and that support uPnP.